# $(this) is not working in click event defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".tabs-item").click(() => {
    $(".tabs-item").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active"); //This line is not at all working..
    });
  });
```

`$(this)` is not at all working. I have been trying with different methods.
Like

```
$("tabs-item").click(() => {
  var x = $(this).attr("tab-data");
  console.log(x);
});
```

All I have got is Undefined for every attribute i have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow function preserves the outer context - `this` refers to the context where the arrow function was defined. Replace arrow function with function declaration to let `jQuery` bind the appropriate context for the function.

```
$("tabs-item").click(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr("tab-data");
    console.log(x);
});
```

Or with arrow function you can get the `event` parameter in the parameters and access `currentTarget` property of it.

```
$("tabs-item").click((event) => {
    var x = $(event.currentTarget).attr("tab-data");
    console.log(x);
});
```

Function declaration approach is more preferable, because arrow functions are not provided for the event handlers. Just use function declaration and it's context will be bound to appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this instead?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tabs-item").click(function(e){
       $(".tabs-item").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

I don't see any special need for using the fat arrow `=>` function notation.